# Does a photo-excited semiconductor produce a constant voltage output equal to the band gap?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

Does the voltage produced by a photo-excited semiconductor always equal the band gap of that semiconductor, or does the voltage vary over a range similar to the photon energies in the emission spectra of that semi-conductor?

In other words, if you shined a laser of a single wave length onto a photovoltaic call that happened to have a band gap equal to that lasers wave length, then would the energy absorption be ~100%?

Answer (score 0):

The voltage of a PV cell doesn't depend (much) on the wavelength of the light as long as the wavelength lies within the range of wavelengths it absorbs. This is because if you use a wavelength higher than the band gap the excited electron will rapidly thermalise to the bottom of the conduction band, so the extra photon energy is dissipated as heat.

If you use light that matches the band gap then the light absorption will be near 100%, but sadly that doesn't mean the PV is 100% efficient at converting the light energy to electrical power. Wikipedia has [an article on PV cell efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell_efficiency).